# My created views for a list aren't displaying

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a list which I have created multiple different views for. However, when I insert the app onto a page, none of these alternate views are displayed. I can see and interact with these different views if I view the list by clicking on it through site contents. They don't display once the list is added.

Comment: Is it really an app oder a webpart you are placing onto a page?

Comment: It's an app part.

Comment: is it sharepoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 0):

Put the page in edit mode, click on edit web part and under List Views change the Selected View to the one you want.

Comment: You shouldn't have to go that deep in to change the view every time. I want the general user to have all the created views displayed right at the top of the list. When you click on the list title, it takes you off the site page and gives you a different look at the list with the different views available. I don't understand why these views aren't available once the list is added to the page.

Comment: I don't think that is possible out of the box but this webpart might solve your problem. http://www.ashokraja.me/post/Combining-Multiple-Web-Parts-in-SharePoint-2013-to-create-a-Tab-Pages-WebPart.aspx